# How do I create an xsl template that can write the element's name and value as a KVP then process all sibling and child nodes recursively

Tags: xml, xslt

So i need to create a transform that can return the name of the element and its value in KVP format with a tab delimeter. The trick is, I need the node itself and all its child nodes returned in teh list. Ordering is not important

Xml Sample:

```
<Holding id="Holding_1">
  <HoldingTypeCode tc="2">PolicyType</HoldingTypeCode>
  <HoldingStatus tc="3">ProposedStatus</HoldingStatus>
  <Policy id="Policy_1">
    <PolNumber>0123456789</PolNumber>
    <LineOfBusiness tc="1">LifeBusiness</LineOfBusiness>
  </Policy>
</Holding>
```

In my XSLT I have this call template:

```
<xsl:call-template name="List_Siblings_And_Children_Recursive">
  <xsl:with-param name="Parent" select="//Holding"></xsl:with-param>
</xsl:call-template>
```

And this is the template itself:

```
<xsl:template name="List_Siblings_And_Children_Recursive">
<xsl:param name="Parent"></xsl:param>

<!-- TAB & CRLF CHAR-->
<xsl:variable name="tab">
  <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="CRLF">
  <xsl:text>&#10;&#13;</xsl:text>
</xsl:variable>

<!-- LIST EACH ELEMENT IN THE LIST OF SIBLINGS, RECURSIVELY CHECK FOR ANY CHILDREN -->
<xsl:for-each select="$Parent/*">
  <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="$tab"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  <xsl:value-of select="$CRLF"/>
  <xsl:call-template name="List_Siblings_And_Children_Recursive">
    <xsl:with-param name="Parent" select="./*"></xsl:with-param>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:for-each>
```

What is wrong with my template? The output I'm looking for should come out like:

```
HoldingTypeCode    PolicyType
HoldingStatus      ProposedStatus
Policy
PolNumber     0123456789
LineOfBusiness     LifeBusiness
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is wrong with my template?

AFAICT, the main problem is with the recursive call:

```
<xsl:call-template name="List_Siblings_And_Children_Recursive">
  <xsl:with-param name="Parent" select="./*"></xsl:with-param>
</xsl:call-template>
```

I believe it should be:

```
<xsl:call-template name="List_Siblings_And_Children_Recursive">
  <xsl:with-param name="Parent" select="."></xsl:with-param>
</xsl:call-template>
```

---

Note that XSLT's native [processing model](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#section-Processing-Model) is recursive, so you could make this a lot simpler by taking advantage of it - say something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;&#13;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note also the difference between:

```
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
```

and:

```
<xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
```

Comment: Assuming that "Holding" isn't the root node, but is within this Xpath. How do I write that template:
//TXLife/TXLifeRequest/OLifE/Holding

Comment: I am afraid that's not very clear. Do you want to ignore the rest of the document and only process the contents of Holding node/s?

Comment: Yes. And the content of a couple of other locations. There are some nodes in the structure that return time stamps and other metadata that I am not interested in obtaining.

I'm trying to compare this output to the output from another similar service to ensure that the values and structure are matching between the two.

Comment: @ShaneSloan Add another template that matches the root node and applies templates (only) to the nodes you do want to process.

Comment: Yep, I'll go read some on that. I'm still pretty lost. Apologies and thanks for your patience. XSL is like voo-doo to me as compared to programming

Comment: "*I'm still pretty lost.*" If you still can't make it work, edit your question and post a more complete example.